# return custom instance from class without lost access to original instance

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk, gtk3, python-3.7

I have a class like that:

```
class Item:
    def __init__(self, name: str, label: str, children: Callable[..., Gtk.Widget]) -> None:
        self.label = Gtk.Label(label)
        [...]

        self._children = children()
        [...]

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        children = super().__getattribute__('_children')
        return children.__getattribute__(item)
```

So I can do things like that:

```
item = Item(name, 'label', Gtk.Entry)
item.set_text('text') # it'll return result from item._children.set_text
item.label.set_text('text') # it'll return result from item.label.set_text
```

but I can't access instance directly because it's returning 'Item' instead 'children' instance:

```
print(type(item)) # it'll return <class 'Item'> instead <class 'Gtk.Entry'>
```

I've tried to write a custom `__new__` method but seems impossible to change instance to _children without lost access to the default instance (in this way I can't access item.label).

Any suggestion?

PS.: 'children' can be any Gtk.Widget

Comment: So you want `item` to be an instance of `Item` or not?

Comment: @Goyo I want `item` to be an instance of class received by `children` parameter (Gtk.Entry in this case), but without lost access to objects inside Item instance. So `type(item)` will be `Gtk.Entry (children)` but when I call `item.label` it'll be `Item.label`

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do here. Your method calls seem to work as desired so why do you care about what `type(item)` returns? But if you really need it to return some specific class then don't make it an instance of another class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manage to solve it using a function to create the class:

```
def item_factory(children: Callable[..., Gtk.Widget]) -> Any:
    class Item(children):
        def __init__(self, name: str, label: str) -> None:
            super().__init__()

            self.label = Gtk.Label(label)
            [...]

    return Item

item = item_factory(Gtk.Entry)(name, label)
item.set_text('text')
item.label.set_text('text')
print(type(item)) # return <class 'Gtk.Entry'>
```

simple and pretty

thanks @Ramazan Polat for showing me the right direction

Comment: if you consider you question answered, please mark it as accepted answer. You can even choose your own answer as accepted. That's the point of SO. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want `Item` instance to be `Gtk.Entry`, then inherit your class from `Gtk.Entry`

```
class Item(Gtk.Entry):
    ...
```

On the other hand, if you want your class inherit from another dynamically, you shoud use metaclass.

```
class ItemFactory:
    @staticmethod
    def create_from(label, target):
        return type('Item', (target,), dict(label=label))


item = ItemFactory.create_from('label', Gtk.Entry)
item.set_text('text')
item.label.set_text('text')
```

Comment: As I said, 'children' can be any Gtk.Widget, not just Gtk.Entry

Comment: Ok, so you want to be able to use any class as ``children``? Then make ``Item`` type to be that ``children``? Am I correct?

Comment: Right @Ramazan Polat, but in that case I can't know type of children at class creation, I must do it at runtime, dynamically

Comment: @LaraMaia Now Just to clarify, you want your class inherit from another class and it will be dynamic, meaning user will choose which class it inherits?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181216/discussion-between-ramazan-polat-and-lara-maia).